# Draw a rotated image directly to Graphics object, without creating a new Bitmap

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap

I was able to make an image to rotate by drawing on a separate graphics object, which draws on a separate Bitmap, and then draw the bitmap with the graphics object, which draws on the final image. This is drawing two basically same images. And I don't want that. The project is a simple graphics engine, so drawing time must be as fast as possible. On top of that, System.Graphics has not proven to be too good at drawing images.

Here is the code I am using. It needs an improvement or two, but the basic method should be visible.

```
    public static System.Drawing.Bitmap rotatedImage(System.Drawing.Bitmap img, double deg, bool hq)
    {
        int diag = (int)Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(img.Width * img.Width + img.Height * img.Height));
        System.Drawing.Bitmap res = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(diag, diag);
        System.Drawing.Graphics gfx = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(res);
        if (hq) gfx.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        DoublePair rotCent = new DoublePair(diag / 2, diag / 2);
        gfx.TranslateTransform((float)rotCent.a, (float)rotCent.b);
        gfx.RotateTransform((float)deg);
        gfx.TranslateTransform((-1) * (float)rotCent.a, (-1) * (float)rotCent.b);
        gfx.DrawImage(img, (diag - img.Width) / 2, (diag - img.Height) / 2, img.Width, img.Height);
        return res;
    }
```

Drawing a rotated image on a new Bitmap requires to rotate the graphics object, which is used for drawing. What I can do is pass the main graphics object to the method, rotate it to draw the image and then rotate the object back. But I don't know if rotating a graphics for a large image is faster or slower than rotating a graphics for a small image.

So, which is going to be faster - to rotate the whole graphics object twice (rotate to draw the image and then rotate back), or to draw the rotated image with a separate graphics and then draw it with the main graphics object? Is there an option to rotate an image without having to use a separate graphics object and without having to rotate a graphics object?

Comment: Rotating a bitmap is pretty expensive, it always requires interpolation.  And of course it gets progressively more expensive the larger the bitmap, cost is O(n^2).  It is quite unclear why you create another bitmap at all, no need for that when you paint, just add an extra Graphics argument to the method so you can pass the e.Graphics property you got from the Paint event.

Comment: Please note: The `Graphics` object does not __contain__ any graphics; it is a **tool** that lets you draw onto a related bitmap, including a control's surface. Hans nails it: __just add an extra Graphics argument to the method signature so you can pass the e.Graphics property you got from the Paint event.__

Comment: So I have to rotate the whole thing, draw the image and then rotate back?

Comment: The problem is this line `System.Drawing.Bitmap res = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(diag, diag);`.  You are creating a brand new bitmap every frame, don't do that.  Instead, create the bitmap once, as a field level variable, clear it, and draw your new frame over top.  It will be significant'y faster.  The basic double buffer pattern you are using is the correct way to do this, don't change it.

Comment: This method is not going to be used for images with the same sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did in the last project was this one, this is inside Paint event, you dont need to create new bitmap, just reset transform and draw the image again:

```
e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(Width/2, Height/2);
e.Graphics.RotateTransform(45f);  //45 degree
e.Graphics.DrawImage(.... //original image

e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(Width/2, Height/2);
e.Graphics.RotateTransform(60f);  //60degree
e.Graphics.DrawImage(.... //original image
...
```